# MongoDB: Unset nested field in array

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in a MongoDB that look like this:

```json
  {
    "parserErgebnis": [
      {
        "values": {
          "prop1": {
            "status": "OK",
            "wert": "03.00"
          },
          "prop2": {
            "status": "OK",
            "wert": "1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "values": {
          "prop1": {
            "status": "OK",
            "wert": "03.00"
          },
          "prop5": {
            "status": "OK",
            "wert": "1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to unset all fields 'status'. I know that an unset for a certain status would look like this:

```js
db.collection.update({},
{
  $unset: {
    "parserErgebnis.$[].values.prop1.status": 1
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

However, I want to remove all 'status' fields in one go (without even knowing how the props are basically named). I basically need a kind of wildcard mechanism like this (PSEUDOCODE NOT WORKING):

```js
db.collection.update({},
{
  $unset: {
    "parserErgebnis.$[].values.*.status": 1
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

Is there a way to get this working or is there an alternative approach? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight way to remove a property from a dynamic prop, but you can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `parserErgebnis` array
- `$objectToArray` convert `values` object to an array in key-value (k-v) format
- `$map` to iterate loop of the above converted (k-v) array, and return `k` as it is and `v` value excludes the status property
- `$arrayToObject` converts values back to an object
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object and newly updated `values` object

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      parserErgebnis: {
        $map: {
          input: "$parserErgebnis",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                values: {
                  $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: {
                      input: { $objectToArray: "$$this.values" },
                      in: {
                        k: "$$this.k",
                        v: {
                          wert: "$$this.v.wert"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{ multi: true })
```

[Playrgound](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GUCNitpnyvZ)

> The [update()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method depreciated, You can use [updateMany()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) method.